Reading and decrypting files on MIFARE DESFire EV1 vs EV3 smart cards
I have a problem with reading and decrypting EV1 and EV3 versions of MIFARE DESFire smart cards. I'm using Dot Net 8.0 and C#, both on Windows and Linux, and PCSC sharp.
If I read and decrypt EV3 card in one specific way, everything works, but only for EV3 cards. For EV1 card I get SW1 SW2 = 0x67, 0x00. This code is:
internal static byte[] ReadEV3(SCardReader reader, int filekey, Kriptografija? kripto) {
    byte[] cmd = [0xBD, .. new byte[] { (byte)filekey }, .. new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }];
    byte[] res = new byte[2048];
    var sta = reader.Transmit(cmd, ref res);
    // Error handling code omitted for brevity, but for EV1 cards SW1 SW2 = 0x67 0x00
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    if (res[0] == 0xAF) // If APDU cmd is set as in the beginning, first unfinished block will be prefixed with 0xAF. {
        data = res.Skip(1).ToArray();
        bool af = true;
        while (af) {
            byte[] cmdAF = [0x90, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
            res = new byte[2048];
            sta = reader.Transmit(cmdAF, ref res);
            // Error handling code omitted for brevity.
            data = [.. data, .. res.Take(res.Length - 2)];
            if (sw2 == 0x00)
                af = false;
    } else
        data = res;
    if (kripto != null)
        data = Decrypt(data, cmd, kripto); // Decrypt method is common for the two Read methods!!!
    return NoTrailingZeros(data);
}

If I read cards in a slightly different way, supposedly with APDU command in ISO 7816 "wrapper", then I can read all cards but I can not decrypt a content of an encrypted file. Reading of unencrypted file is fine. This code is:
internal static byte[] Read(SCardReader reader, int filekey, Kriptografija? kripto) {
    byte[] cmd = 
        [0x90, 0xBD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, .. new byte[] { (byte)filekey }, .. new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }];
    byte[] res = new byte[2048];
    var sta = reader.Transmit(cmd, ref res);
    // Error handling code omitted for brevity.
    byte[] data = res.Take(res.Length - 2).ToArray();
    if (sw2 == 0xAF) { // If APDU cmd is set as in the beginning, no blocks are prefixed with AF, but suffixed with 91 AF.
        bool af = true;
        byte[] cmdAF = [0x90, 0xAF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
        while (af) {
            res = new byte[2048];
            sta = reader.Transmit(cmdAF, ref res);
            // Error handling code omitted for brevity.
            data = [.. data, .. res.Take(res.Length - 2)];
            if (sw2 == 0x00) 
                af = false;
        }
    }
    if (kripto != null)
        data = Decrypt(data, cmd, kripto); // Decrypt method is common for the two Read methods!!!
    return NoTrailingZeros(data);
}

Decrypt method is like this:
private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] enc, byte[] cmd, Kriptografija kripto) {
    // Error handling and validation code omitted for brevity.
    kripto.SessionIV = kripto.CMAC(cmd); // The only thing different in calls to Decrypt is command content and size.
    byte[] newIV = enc.Skip(enc.Length - 16).Take(16).ToArray();
    byte[] data = Kriptografija.AesDecrypt(kripto.SessionKey, kripto.SessionIV.ToArray(), enc, CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode.None);
    kripto.SessionIV = newIV;
    return data;
}

So, what's the catch?
What am I doing wrong?
I do not have a problem with similar code bases in Java (both for Android and desktop) but there I use appropriate NXP SDK. Alas, there's no such SDK for anything Dot Net.
I also tried to decrypt data block by block, after each Transmit, including "Give me more" command, although ReadEV3 does work OK without that, and although Logcat on Android indicates that this is not necessary.
NXP's SDKs are closed source and not decompilable.

**** EDIT ****

I've found a workaround, which was actually accepted as a solution on NXP's forum here.

It's going to require to setup a test environment for testing your issue, and even then we cannot just run your code as it clearly depends on a wrapper class Kriptografija (don't use wrapper classes unless for specific functionality!) and key derivation that is not shown. So basically you're betting that somebody can spot a bug by just reading the code. Here's to hoping you get lucky, but please don't try and hold your breath waiting for an answer.

Right.
But, since Kriptografija is obviously working in one scenario, I doubt there's problem with that class. There might be, but that - decryption - is a question of secondary importance.
The question of main importance is why that scenario does not work on older EV1 cards. And that problem - reading smart cards - might be obvious to someone looking at my code.

I did implement a lot of that, but to me that was some intermediate fun before moving on to more interesting issues. Unfortunately it was erased from memory within about a month. The one thing that I remember is that for some memory cards like DESFire, the final ciphertext was used for the next element, kind of like an continuous CBC mode...

Yes, exactly, I do that. I think. :-) You decrypt next block with CMAC-ed current command and last 16 bytes of current block.
It seems that "current" command doest not include "give me more" command, but I also did that case, without any result.
Do you see something wrong with command themselves, and why, depending on command form, are answers somewhat different regarding prefix and suffix?
